# Accessing individual item from model in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

In MVC 5, i am looping through the **Model item** in my view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.invoices)
```

During each loop i am calling a **partial view**

```
@{     
       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Invoice/CommonSegment.cshtml", item);
 }
```

But i am not able to access **model** ('item') in **CommonSegment.cshtml**

[Snap from Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyw3.png)

```
            <tr>
                <td class="orderTitle">@item.orderId.label</td>
                <td class="orderValue">@item.orderId.value</td>
            </tr>
```

I am referring to same model in View and PartialView.

I wouldn't like to go with **ViewBag**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should access item, what it show?

Comment: What do you mean _not able to access item_?

Comment: What is model type of your partial view?, it should be Model.Invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do this during the Loop,

```
@foreach (var item in Model.invoices)
{
   @Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Invoice/CommonSegment.cshtml", item);
}
```

But why writing foreach loops when you can use editor templates.

```
@model IEnumerable<Invoices>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then simply define the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Invoice/CommonSegment.cshtml`) It will automatically rendered for each element of your model:

```
@model Invoices
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.abc)
</div>
```